# How to overcome preg_match 'offset is higher than subject length'?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

The pattern `~(\w+-?)+[0-9]+(?=\.html)~` returns false on `www.test.com/this/works/12345678901234567/2009/08/2009819107554384978.html`

But it returns 1 on `www.test.com/this/works/12345678901234567/2009/08/200981910755438497.html` (one character less).

The PHP documentation reads:

> 'Returns FALSE if offset is higher than subject length.'

How so?

[Live test here](https://en.functions-online.com/preg_match.html?command=%7B%22pattern%22:%22~(%5C%5Cw%20-?)%20[0-9]%20(?=%5C%5C.html)~%22,%22subject%22:%22www.test.com%5C/this%5C/works%5C/12345678901234567%5C/2009%5C/08%5C/200981910755438497.html%22%7D).

Comment: It is due to the catastrophic backtracking. Use [`'~\w+(?:-\w+)*[0-9]+(?=\.html)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/xsapiG/1).

Comment: It's still not clear to me if this is a fixable syntax issue (if so how), or if I have to re-think the regex.

Comment: Although it has issues on greediness, I can't reproduce https://3v4l.org/DSW4Z

Comment: Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/WDtjtA

Comment: Now you changed the input. If you read second duplicate marked question, you will find some useful info.

Comment: To find the error you could use `preg_last_error()` as in `var_dump(preg_last_error() === PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR);` which returns `true`.